# Access a file in a python script that is stored in HDFS distributed cache

Tags: python, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I have a python script that needs to access and query a MaxMind (.mmdb) file type.  My current thought is to load the MaxMind file into HDFS's distributed cache and then pass it through Pig to my Python script.  MY current Pig Script is:

```
SET mapred.cache.file /path/filelocation/;
SET mapred.createsymlink YES;
SET mapred.cache.file hdfs://localserver:8020/pathtofile#filename;
REGISTER 'pythonscript' USING jython AS myudf;
logfile= LOAD 'filename' USING PigStorage(',') AS (x:int);
RESULT = FOREACH logfile GENERATE myudf.pyFunc(x,"how to pass in MaxMind file");
```

Any thoughts as to how to access the file once its loaded in to the distribute cache inside of the python script?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
set mapred.cache.files hdfs:///user/cody.stevens/testdat//list.txt#filename;
SET mapred.createsymlink YES; 
REGISTER 'my.py' USING jython AS myudf;
a = LOAD 'hdfs:///user/cody.stevens/pig.txt' as (x:chararray);
RESULT = FOREACH a GENERATE myudf.list_files(x,'filename');
STORE RESULT into '$OUTPUT';
```

and here is the corresponding my.py that I used for this example

```
#/usr/bin/env python 
import os 

@outputSchema("ls:chararray}")
def list_files(x,f):
    #ls =  os.listdir('.')
    fin = open(f,'rb')
    return [x,fin.readlines()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "ok"
```

Almost forgot.. I was calling it like this.

```
pig -param OUTPUT=/user/cody.stevens/pigout -f dist.pig
```

It should be in your local dir so python should be able to access it. In that example 'filename' is the name of the symbolic link, you will have to update accordingly. In your case you will want your 'filename' to be your maxmind file, and depending on what your values in 'a' are you may need to change that back to 'as (x:int)'.

Good luck!

Comment: I get the error "syntaxerror no viable alternative at input '&'".  The line I added is:

    var = os.listdir(&quot;datafiles&quot;)

Comment: I updated with more detail above.  This works on my cluster, you may need to change some things to make it work in yours ( filepath obviously won't be /user/cody.stevens etc)

Comment: This seems to work.  I have an issue with Python - SyntaxError 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6 . But I believe that is a separate issue.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes... I had that issue as well because I was doing a

    with open(f 'rb') as fn:

For simplicity and proof of concept I just opened the file the old fashioned way with

    fin = open(f,'rb')

I think it is the jython version complaining.  You could try adding 
    from __future__ import with_statement